# If I’ve already blacklisted nouveau, why is `options nouveau modeset=0` necessary?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nouveau, modprobe

All the instructions for disabling the Nouveau driver (for example, the [official NVidia guide to using CUDA with their proprietary drivers](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#runfile-nouveau)) suggest that you create a `modprobe.d` file with the contents:

```
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
```

This is great, it works. But I don’t understand why it’s suggested to do `options nouveau modeset=0` after blacklisting the driver itself. What does the additional configuration accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at [`nouveau_drm.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/d1587f7bfe9a0f97a75d42ac1489aeda551106bc/drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nouveau_drm.c#L85) and it looks like the module parameter `modeset=0` just disables the driver.

I could be mistaken, but my reading of the two directives is as follows:

1. `blacklist nouveau`: prevent the kernel from loading the `nouveau` module at all.
2. `options nouveau modeset=0`: if the `nouveau` module is built into the kernel directly, disable it.